# Enable 'insert mode maps' when 'paste' option is set

Tags: linux, vim

I'm using VIM 7.4 and I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`, `imap jk <ESC>` to get out of `insert` mode using `jk` but the problem is it doesn't work when I'm in `insert` mode while the `paste` option is set.

According to this wiki [Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))

> if the 'paste' option is set, then insert mode maps are disabled.

Is there a way/mapping to make `imap jk <ESC>` work even when `paste` is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's by design that all insert mode mappings are disabled. Having maps work in paste mode would screw up pasting which is counter productive.

You should only be in paste mode if you are pasting text. (So you should spend as little time as possible in this mode)

The only special key in paste mode is the paste toggle key so you should set that and hit it to exit paste mode. To set paste toggle to f9 you use

```
set pastetoggle=<f9>
```

After this setting is set hitting `<f9>` will enter and leave paste mode. Once you are no longer in paste mode your mappings will work again

Read `:h 'pastetoggle'`